# oracle RAC server addition at DR site after DR occurs

Tags: oracle, cluster, oracle-rac

DB: Oracle 
Server: Physical
OS: Linux 5.5

The production site contains 3 server nodes and will be clustered using Oracle RAC, database replication will be done with the help of Oracle Data guard. As a minimum, the DR site will have a single physical server working in Physical Standby mode.

The situation: 
DR environment is also shared by a testing environment, which has 3 database servers in RAC cluster. These servers will have 2 images, one for Testing network and one for DR network. Now, when the actual DR will happen, the Testing image would be shut down and DR image will start working and will join the 1st Physical DR Server node and eventually becomes a 4 node DR.

I want to know the technical difficulty to achieve this and what could be the potential pain points?

Comment: What do you mean by different "image"? Different copy of operating system?

Comment: Yes, two copy of operating system

Answer (score 0):

This is technically possible, but I would not recommend it.

General pain points of having an inactive instance of operating system sitting on the disk (anywhere, including the DR site) are:

- account management (useradd, passwd)
- patching OS (security, compatibility)
- patching Oracle  (security, compatibility)
- patching any other auxiliary software, like monitoring tools or backup tools
- changing hardware
- changing settings of OS
- changing settings of Oracle
- changing settings of any other auxiliary software

General pain points of sharing hardware between dev and DR:

- developers ALWAYS face a crucial deadline, period. Having a deadline is their job. They will fiercely oppose shutting down their environment for whatever reason. DR tests (or any other work) would be performed by YOU around midnight on Saturday/Sunday.

Comment: Around here the best way to say "thanks" is by voting the answer up, and by accepting the best answer. Cheers.